# Follow up questions

Tags: discussion

If your original Stack Exchange question is answered and you have additional follow up questions, please create new Stack Exchange questions to ask them. 
Comments should not be used for separate follow up questions or extensive troubleshooting.

Stack Exchange Q&A readability and indexing is much better when the scope of each question is clearly defined in the question itself.

Comments can be helpful to clarify minor points needed in order to provide quality answers. If a comment is made to request you clarify your question, please edit your original question instead of responding with additional comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*What Smart Kid♦ said.*

I fully agree and would like to add that it's a very good feature to have related questions and follow-up questions. While the right sidebar automatically suggests related questions, it's always a good thing to **link related questions** if you think it's important enough to mention. This also shows you did a good research on your issue.

For example:

#### questions/1337/my-general-problem-solver-panics-at-main

> I've written a simple problem solver that allows to basically find a solution to any problem you may have.
>
> [image: solver workflow]
>
> But when I run it:
>
> ```
> $ solve all
> ```
>
> it simple exits and I can not find out why. Here is the critical source:
>
> ```
> use std::env;
> fn main() {
>     for problem in env::args() {
>         solve(problem);
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> and the stack trace:
>
> ```
> panicked at 'called `Problems::solve()` on a `None` value', /Users/user/src/rust-buildbot/slave/nightly-dist-rustc-mac/build/src/libsolver/general.rs:4
> thread '<main>' panicked at 'Some problems missing', /Users/user/src/rust-buildbot/slave/nightly-dist-rustc-mac/build/src/libsolver/general.rs:4
> ```
>
> Any idea why it does not solve my problem? I also tried to solve it using the solver, but same issue.

#### questions/1342/how-to-generate-random-problems-for-my-solver

> As I recently found out in [my previous question about my general problem solver panicking at main](https://monero.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154/follow-up-questions), I did not have enough random problems to solve. Now my follow-up question is:
>
> How to generate random problems for my general solver? I tried [random.org/problems](http://random.org/problems) but received 404 errors. Also `/dev/rproblem/` seems not to provide enough entropy to randomize problems for my solver. This is the basic workflow:
>
> [image: general problem solving uml]
>
> A very dedicated search on Google did not help either. It seems I'm the first developer trying to write a general problem solver.

And voila, your previous question will show up in the sidebar, visible for everyone:

[image: linked items in the sidebar]

Happy posting!